# Holding a Map of functions with differing number of args

Tags: java, design-patterns, functional-programming, functional-interface

I am trying to write a utility class that can take in a `String` and `Class<?>` and return back an `Object` that is really the typed instance of that `String`.

For example, if I have string `"FALSE"` and class `"java.lang.Boolean"`, I want to return the typed `Boolean.FALSE`. Etc for other classes like String, Long, Int, Enum, etc.

I want to do this in a way that doesn't need too much re-writing when a new type is added. Currently I have a method with signature `Object getTypedValue(Class<?> clazz, String value);`.

From here, I thought I could use a `Map<Class<?>, Function<String, Object>>`. This works fine for cases like String and Boolean, but with the Enum case, I need the class name as well. So then the Map becomes `Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<String, Class<?>, Object>>`.

But most of the methods do not need the Class parameter. Have also found that a new FunctionalInterface like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface OptionalClassFunction<T, CLAZZ, R> {

  R apply(T t, CLAZZ... clazz);

}
```

does not seem to work when I pass a method with only the T as the lambda.

e.g.

```
ImmutableMap.of(
  Boolean.class, Util::toBoolean
)

private Boolean toBoolean(String value);
```

does not work.

Any suggestions on how to so something like:

`Map<Class<?>, WhateverFunction<String, MAYBE_A_CLASS, Object>>` ?

Example methods would be:

```
  public static Boolean toBoolean(String value) {
    // derive bool
  }

  public static Enum toEnum(String value, Class<?> fieldType) {
    // derive enum
  }
```

Comment: There are not a finite number of enums in the system; this is a library used in a large ecosystem with thousands of enums registered. Imagine we have `DayOfTheWeek`, `Month`, `AstrologicalSign`, etc. Then called this method `toEnum` with `toEnum("AUGUST", `Month.class`)`

Comment: I don't see the difference between `Util.toEnum("AUGUST", Month.class)` and `Month.valueOf("AUGUST")`, except that the first is longer, requires a homegrown method, and needs a cast if assigned to a `Month` variable, while the second is shorter, built-in, and type-safe.

Comment: Ah. Maybe I explained it wrong. This class is derived from a string and attempted to be serialized. So we would have to do something like: Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(“Month.class”). If there is a cleaner way to cast an ad-hoc string to this ad-hoc class, I’m happy to use the native method

Comment: This question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454). You're looking for a way to get `Enum.class` mapped to a parser, but even if you solved that, it wouldn't work for you, because you wouldn't be looking up `Enum.class`, you would be looking up e.g. `DayOfWeek.class`, and hence wouldn't find the parser. --- Take a step back, then ask your *real* (new) question, i.e. the fact that you have e.g. `"java.lang.Integer", "42"` as inputs and want an `Integer(42)` object as result, or a `"java.time.DayOfWeek", "MONDAY"` as inputs and want a `DayOfWeek.MONDAY` object.

Comment: This is fair. Will do. Thanks @Andreas.

Comment: Have done so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084662/creating-a-parser-of-class-name-string-value-to-a-typed-value

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need the class name for enums?

E.g. [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) is an `enum`, and like every other `enum` class, it has a [`valueOf(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) method, so simply register this:

```
DayOfWeek.class, DayOfWeek::valueOf
```

If you don't like the `valueOf` method, e.g. because it is case-sensitive, and your `toEnum` method is better, then write a helper method to encapsulate that, e.g.

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Function<String, T> getEnumParser(Class<T> type) {
    return s -> toEnum(s, type);
}

public static <T extends Enum<T>> T toEnum(String value, Class<T> type) {
    for (T constant : type.getEnumConstants())
        if (constant.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value))
            return constant;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown constant for enum " + type.getName() + ": \"" + value + "\"");
}
```

You then register it using:

```
DayOfWeek.class, Util.getEnumParser(DayOfWeek.class)
```

The helper is nice, but you don't really need it:

```
DayOfWeek.class, s -> Util.toEnum(s, DayOfWeek.class)
```

except that might confuse the compiler when used with `ImmutableMap.of(...)`. The helper fixes that potential compiler inference problem.

Comment: the latter of the two is working currently with a BiFunction. The question arises because Enum is the _only_ case (so far) that requires this class argument. So passing that class argument to every type's parser seems wrong. 

Also, as mentioned elsewhere, it is not prudent to define enums individually here, as it is a generic library where the types of enums are not known beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on how to so something like:
>
> ```
> Map<Class<?>, WhateverFunction<String, MAYBE_A_CLASS, Object>>
> ```

Always make it a `BiFunction`, and simply ignore the `Class<?>` parameter:

```
Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<String, Class<?>, Object>> map = Map.of(
        Boolean.class, (s,t) -> Util.toBoolean(s),
        Enum.class, Util::toEnum
);
```

Since the user of the map wouldn't know if the `Class<?>` parameter is needed, it would have to always pass the value, e.g.

```
Class<?> type = ...
String value = ...

Object obj = map.get(type).apply(value, type);
```

*Simplified. You'd normally check for null after the `get()` call.*

Of course, that won't work either, because the caller thinks the type is e.g. `DayOfWeek`, so if caller does `type = DayOfWeek.class`, the lookup would fail. Now suddenly the logic needed by the caller is getting complex.

Solution for that is to encapsulate the `get-apply` logic in a helper method, so you can substitute `DayOfWeek.class` with `Enum.class` for the map lookup, but if you do that, you might as well just build in straight support for enums, bypassing the map, and leave the map with `Function`.