# Creating a parser of Class name + String value to a typed value

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, functional-programming, functional-interface

I am trying to write a method that can take in a String classname and a String value, and return the value represented as that String.

Example inputs:

```
parse("java.lang.String", "abc") -> String "ABC"
parse("java.lang.Boolean", "FALSE") -> Boolean FALSE
parse("java.lang.Integer", "123") -> Integer 123
parse("com.me.Color", "RED") -> enum Color.RED
```

I have found that if I use an if block containing `assignableFrom` calls, I can achieve this. But would prefer writing something more extendable, so it isn't as difficult to add a new parser tomorrow.

This is what I have now:

```
    String stringClassName = //stringified full class name
    String value = //value to parse
    Class<?> fieldType = Class.forName(stringClassName)
    if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
      return value;
    } else if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)) {
      return Util.toBoolean(value);
    } else if (fieldType.isEnum()) {
      return Util.toEnum(fieldType, value);
    } else {
      // throw exception
    }
```

Comment: All the example input types have a static `#valueOf(String)` method. You could try invoking that method via reflection. Though they aren't all semantically the same; for instance, `Integer#valueOf(String)` will throw an exception if the string cannot be parsed into an integer, but `Boolean#valueOf(String)` will return `false` if the string is not "true" (ignoring case).

Comment: @Slaw, I am aware of the static methods, and those Utils do something similar. What I am asking for is a better way to route to the specific parser without having to add an `else-if` block in the future. Once I know the type, this is a simple problem. Finding the appropriately assignable type is the issue.

Comment: If you want to use the `valueOf` method, just do `Class.forName(...).getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, arg)`. This will of course fail if the class does not have a public, static `#valueOf(String)` method.

Comment: Fair. Thanks for the thought. I want to avoid `valueOf` for now because 1) this breaks when I want to serialize custom classes, and 2) Boolean.valueOf() is laughably bad.

Comment: Understandable. The other option I was going to suggest is an interface, but I see codeflush.dev has already given an answer. Only thing I'd add to that is, if you want, you can make use of `ServiceLoader` so you don't have to manually register parser instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. For example:

You could have an interface called `Parser`

```java
package example;

public interface Parser {

    boolean canParse(String fullQualifiedClassName);
    Object parse(String fullQualifiedClassName, String value) throws ParseException;

    class ParseException extends Exception {

        public ParseException(String msg) {
            super(msg);
        }

        public ParseException(Exception cause) {
            super(cause);
        }
    }
}
```

And all your Default-Implementations in an Enum or statically defined in another way:

```java
package example;

public enum DefaultParser implements Parser {

    STRING {
        @Override
        public boolean canParse(String fullQualifiedClassName) {
            return isClassAssignableFromClassName(fullQualifiedClassName, String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Object parse(String fullQualifiedClassName, String value) throws ParseException {
            return value;
        }
    },
    ENUM {
        @Override
        public boolean canParse(String fullQualifiedClassName) {
            return isClassAssignableFromClassName(fullQualifiedClassName, Enum.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Object parse(String fullQualifiedClassName, String value) throws ParseException {
            final Class<? extends Enum> clazz;
            try {
                clazz = (Class<? extends Enum>) Class.forName(fullQualifiedClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new ParseException(e);
            }

            return Enum.valueOf(clazz, value);
        }
    },
    BOOLEAN {
        @Override
        public boolean canParse(String fullQualifiedClassName) {
            return isClassAssignableFromClassName(fullQualifiedClassName, Boolean.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Object parse(String fullQualifiedClassName, String value) throws ParseException {
            return value.toLowerCase().equals("true");
        }
    };

    private static boolean isClassAssignableFromClassName(String fullQualifiedClassName, Class<?> clazz) {
        try {
            return clazz.isAssignableFrom(Class.forName(fullQualifiedClassName));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And a `ParentParser` Implementation that combines multiple Parsers into one:

```java
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class ParentParser implements Parser {

    private final List<Parser> parsers;

    public ParentParser() {
        this.parsers = new ArrayList<>();
        this.parsers.addAll(Arrays.asList(DefaultParser.values()));
    }

    public void register(Parser parser) {
        this.parsers.add(parser);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canParse(String fullQualifiedClassName) {
        return findParser(fullQualifiedClassName).isPresent();
    }

    @Override
    public Object parse(String fullQualifiedClassName, String value) throws ParseException {
        return findParser(fullQualifiedClassName)
              .orElseThrow(() -> new ParseException("no registered parser found for class=" + fullQualifiedClassName))
              .parse(fullQualifiedClassName, value);
    }

    private Optional<Parser> findParser(String fullQualifiedClassName) {
        return this.parsers.stream().filter(parser -> parser.canParse(fullQualifiedClassName)).findAny();
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```java
package example;

import example.Parser.ParseException;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final ParentParser parser = new ParentParser();

        System.out.println(parser.parse("java.lang.String", "hello world"));
        System.out.println(parser.parse("java.lang.Boolean", "true"));
        System.out.println(parser.parse("java.time.DayOfWeek", "TUESDAY"));
    }
}
```

And you could add more parsers, for example a parser using Jackson (JSON):

```java
package example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import example.Parser.ParseException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final ParentParser parser = new ParentParser();

        System.out.println(parser.parse("java.lang.String", "hello world"));
        System.out.println(parser.parse("java.lang.Boolean", "true"));
        System.out.println(parser.parse("java.time.DayOfWeek", "TUESDAY"));

        parser.register(new JacksonParser());

        System.out.println(parser.parse("java.util.Map", "{\"key\":\"value\"}"));
    }

    private static class JacksonParser implements Parser {

        private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

        @Override
        public boolean canParse(String fullQualifiedClassName) {
            final Class<?> clazz;
            try {
                clazz = Class.forName(fullQualifiedClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                return false;
            }

            return MAPPER.canDeserialize(MAPPER.constructType(clazz));
        }

        @Override
        public Object parse(String fullQualifiedClassName, String value) throws ParseException {
            try {
                return MAPPER.readValue(value, Class.forName(fullQualifiedClassName));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                throw new ParseException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this can of course be optimized depending on your needs.
If your Parser-Implementations can only parse a static List of Types and there is only one Parser-Implementation per Class, you should change the `List<Parser>` to `Map<Class<?>, Parser>` and change the register-Method to `register(Class<?> clazz, Parser parser)` for example

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic solution using reflection apis in java.
That would reduce a lot amount of code and would be more extensible.
Also not there is a separate processing required for enum types.
I have covered the basic cases in the code shown below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        Object instance1 = parse("java.lang.String", "abc", false);
        Object instance2 = parse("java.lang.Boolean", "FALSE", false);
        Object instance3 = parse("java.lang.Integer", "123", false);
        Object instance4 = parse("com.me.Color", "RED", true);
    }

    private static Object parse(String className, String argument, boolean isEnum) throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException {
        if (isEnum) {
            Object value = Enum.valueOf((Class<? extends Enum>) Class.forName(className), argument);
            //System.out.println(value);
            return value;
        } else {
            return parse(className, new Object[]{argument}, isEnum);
        }
    }

    private static Object parse(String className, Object[] arguments, boolean isEnum) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
        Object object = ctor.newInstance(arguments);
        //System.out.println(object);
        return object;
    }
```